# Assigning Session value in javascript through variable

Tags: javascript

I have a question. in javascript, assigning a direct value to a session variable is possible as like the following:

```
'<%=Session["name"]="antony";%>'
```

But how to assign a value through  variable as like the following:

```
var val={"antony","francis"};
'<%=Session["name"]="' + val[0] + '"; %>'
```

The above is not working. Is there any other way to assign a variable containing value to a session variable?

Thanks

Comment: Your getting your client side code and your server side code all mixed up. You can't do what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because the `Session` is in the **`server-side`** context and javascript variables in the **`client-side`** context. You can se the value of session printing it out the javascript code, but pass a value of javascript variable don't.

As an alternative, you could make a call ([async `request` using ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), for sample) to the server and pass the value of javascript variable in this call and there make a code to set the value in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what your trying to do:

```
var val={"antony","francis"};
```

runs client side (it's calculated on the browser **after** the page has downloaded)

```
<%=Session["name"]="
```

runs server side. It is calculated **before** the page is sent to the browser. So `<%=Session["name"]="' + val[0] + '"; %>` is trying to access the variable `val` that doesn't exist yet.